# How to add new elements to chosen, when searching on chosen select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to add new value not in chosen.
I have set 'no_results_text' as `<a>` tag. its working.
`$('#secondary_diagnosis').chosen({no_results_text: '<a onclick="add_new_diagnosis()">Save as New </a>'});`
[image]

This is my Code:

But if i want add new value in half of exiting value, then 'no_results_text' not showing. i need solution for call my predefined function `add_new_diagnosis()`.

How Can i put `<a>` tags on the `chosen-search-input`?
[image]

Current code:

```
<select class="col-md-11" name="secondary_diagnosis" id="secondary_diagnosis"
      class="form-control chosen" title="Diagnosis">
          <option value="0">Other</option>
          <option value="0">other retinal</option>
          <option value="0">Couch</option>
          <option value="0">Fever</option>
</select>
```

```
window.onload = function () {
        $('#secondary_diagnosis').chosen({no_results_text: '<a onclick="add_new_diagnosis()">Save as New </a>'});
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the code snippet, please?

Comment: I have shared it on Question now @NadirAbbas

Comment: i need to call my ```add_new_diagnosis()``` function

Comment: Can you provided minimal working example of this like a js fiddle with CDN added and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From using this Data List add the events to the input. It works for me.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" list="diagnosis" name="secondary_diagnosis" id="secondary_diagnosis" onclick=""/>
<datalist id="diagnosis" >
       <option value="0">Other</option>
       <option value="0">other retinal</option>
       <option value="0">Couch</option>
       <option value="0">Fever</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```js
window.onload = function () {
        $('#secondary_diagnosis').chosen({no_results_text: 'Save as New'});
        
        $('.chosen-container').on('click', '.no-results', function(){
           add_new_diagnosis($(this).find('span').text());
           $('#secondary_diagnosis').val('').trigger('chosen:updated');
        });
        
        function add_new_diagnosis(val) {
            console.log(`Add new: ${val}`)
        }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="col-md-11" name="secondary_diagnosis" id="secondary_diagnosis"
      class="form-control chosen" title="Diagnosis">
          <option value="0">Other</option>
          <option value="0">other retinal</option>
          <option value="0">Couch</option>
          <option value="0">Fever</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have done it. as this i want enter ```other re```. how can i enter it ?

Comment: i need solution for this situation

Comment: Do you want to append new option in chosen list?

Comment: Your solution is curret, but i want add some part of existing  word.

Comment: Eg: ```other retinal``` in list. but i want enter ```other re``` only as new.

Comment: `Add new` option will be displayed only if nothing matches with user input. 
If you want to append/prepend something to a user query, you can do that inside `add_new_diagnosis` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [select2](https://select2.org/tagging#automatic-tokenization-into-tags) jquery plugin instead of chosenJS.

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="select2" multiple="multiple">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option selected="selected">purple</option>
</select>
```

Modified as per needs (JS initialization):

```
$("#select2").select2({
    tags: true,
    width: '100%',
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
}).on("change", function(e) {

    var isNew = $(this).find('[data-select2-tag="true"]');
    if(isNew.length && $.inArray(isNew.val(), $(this).val()) !== -1){
        $.post('http://example.com/api/tags/add', { tag: isNew.val() }, function(res){
            if(res) {
                isNew.replaceWith('<option selected value="'+res.tag_id+'">'+res.tag+'</option>');
            } else {
                isNew.remove();
            }
        }, 'json');
    }
});
```